# Question about unique solutions?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If a,b and c are elements of a ring, does the equation ax+b=c always have a solution x? If it does, must the solution be unique?

Comment: In the integers, how about $2x + 1 = 4$?

Comment: The second questions seems to be identical to your previous one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594290/comparison-between-rings-and-groups-question

Comment: In $\;R=\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\;$ , how many solutions do you have for $\;2x=0\;$ ?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, thank you, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

About the existence of a solution: for the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ there exists a solution to $ax=b$ if and only if $a\mid b$. For the ring $M_n(K)$ the matrix equation $AX=B$ is a special case of the Sylverster equation, i.e., $AX+XC=B$. See the discussion here: [Existence of non-trivial solution of Sylvester equation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179413/existence-of-non-trivial-solution-of-sylvester-equation). 
In general, the existence is a difficult issue. Concerning uniqueness, the matrix equation $AX=0$ also shows that there may be many solutions in general.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to consider the equation $ax=b$.

If $b=0$ then the set of solutions coincides with the right annulator of $a$: $N_a=\{x|ax=0\}$. For arbitrary $b$ let $x_0$ is a solution of $ax=b$ (if exists!). Then the set of solutions coincides with the coset $N_a+x_0$.

This is all what one can say about solutions.